# C++/boost: apply a prefix to a string list

Tags: c++, string, boost, prefix

I want to add a simple prefix to a list of strings:

```
Input: "a, b, c, d, e"
Output: ":a, :b, :c, :d, :e"
```

Is there any boost library already implemented for that kind of operations? adding prefixes or even a apply a `boost::format` operation to a sequence of strings?

I have searched on the `boost::algorithm::string` library but found nothing. Of course, I could solve it simply with `std::for_each` or any other mean, but I want to know if there's anything already made.

Comment: How are these string stored? it is a list<string>?

Comment: `std::vector<std::string>` actually, though `boost` and `std` only think in ranges or iterators so, I think the specific container doesn't matter here.

Comment: Is your input one string like in your example or a container of strings?

Comment: `std::regex_replace`?

Comment: @mkaes a `std::vector<std::string>`

Comment: @appleapple too heavy for a simple replacement. Better a classical `for` or a `std::for_each` in that case.

Comment: your question is unclear to me, are `Input` `Output` actually `cin(istream)` and `cout(ostream)`?or they are string? how you get them? how you store them?

Comment: @appleapple Nou, `input` is the input of the algorithm I'm looking for (a list of strings in any container by means of iterators or simply passing the container), and `output` is the output of that algorithm (a new container with the transformed values, the original container modified, or saving on a `output_iterator` of a container of my choice to save the replaced values).

Answer (score 2):

So I will assume that you have a container with strings in it and each of those string should be prefixed:
Maybe like this:

```
std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [](auto& s){ s.insert(0, ":");});
```

or if c++11 is no option like this:

```
string& (string::*FP)(size_t pos, const string& str) = &string::insert;
std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), std::bind(FP, std::placeholders::_1, 0, ":"));
```

This will prefix each element in your container with a `:`.

A full example that will at least produce the output in your example would be like this:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> v;
    v.push_back("a");
    v.push_back("b");
    v.push_back("c");
    v.push_back("d");
    v.push_back("e");
    std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [](auto& s){ s.insert(0, ":");});    
    for(const auto& s : v)
    {
        std::cout << s << ", ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```